# apache airflow idempotent DAG implementation

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow, idempotent

I am generating a `start` and `end` time for an API query using the following:

```py
startTime = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')) - timedelta(hours = 1)
endTime = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

This works great and generates the correct parameters for the API query. But I noticed if the task fails and if I try to rerun the task again it uses new values for `startTime` and `endTime` based on the DAG executed runtime.

I am trying to figure out how I can make this more idempotent so if the task fails I can rerun it and the same `startTime` and `endTime` will be used from the original task execution.

I have read a bit about templates and macros but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Here is the task code. I am using the KubernetesPodOperator.

```py
ant_get_logs = KubernetesPodOperator(
    env_vars={
        "startTime": startTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        "endTime": endTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        "timeZone":'US/Eastern',
        "session":'none',
    },

    volumes=[volume],
    volume_mounts=[volume_mount],

    task_id='ant_get_logs',
    image='test:1.0.0',
    image_pull_policy='Always',
    in_cluster=True,
    namespace=namespace,
    name='kubepod_ant_get_logs',
    random_name_suffix=True,
    labels={'app': 'backend', 'env': 'dev'},
    reattach_on_restart=True,
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    get_logs=True,
    log_events_on_failure=True,
)
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share the full task code ? is it PythonOperator

Comment: @ozs, I updated my post with the task code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easiest way to get an idempotent task with Airflow is by leveraging templates and the `logical/execution_date` variable.

Every **DAG run** and task instance have associated a date interval and a logical date, which depend on the DAG schedule.

In your case, if your DAG have an hourly schedule it will create a new DAG run each hour, with an associated **logical date**. This logical date won't change even if you restart the task, thus ensuring idempotence. So you can rewrite the envars as

```
"startTime": "{{ dag_run.logical_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}"
"endTime": "{{ (dag_run.logical_date + macros.timedelta(hours = 1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}"
```

or

```
"startTime": "{{ data_interval_start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}"
"endTime": "{{ data_interval_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}"
```

> NOTE: you can use templates in the `env_vars` field because it is a templated field in the `KubernetesPodOperator` operator.

I highly suggest you to read [Airflow DAG Runs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html) to better understand the logical date concept and the [Airflow Templates and predefined Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) for a list of all the variables and macros you can use in templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new task that calculate the dates and push it to XCom. In the KubernetesPodOperator pull it.

```
@task(multiple_outputs=True)
def get_times():
    startTime = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')) - timedelta(hours=1)
    endTime = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))

    return {
        "start_time": startTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        "end_time": endTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    }

ant_get_logs = KubernetesPodOperator(
    env_vars={
        "startTime": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_times', key='start_time') }}",
        "endTime": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_times', key='end_time') }}",
        "timeZone":'US/Eastern',
        "session":'none',
    },

    volumes=[volume],
    volume_mounts=[volume_mount],

    task_id='ant_get_logs',
    image='test:1.0.0',
    image_pull_policy='Always',
    in_cluster=True,
    namespace=namespace,
    name='kubepod_ant_get_logs',
    random_name_suffix=True,
    labels={'app': 'backend', 'env': 'dev'},
    reattach_on_restart=True,
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    get_logs=True,
    log_events_on_failure=True,
)
```

Comment: I will give it a try. This will be idempotent? If I have to rerun the dag it will use the original start/end times from original execution? Thanks!

Comment: the times are calculated once and saved as XCOM, so if the KubernetesPodOperator task fails and retry it will be  the same values cause it was already calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Like someone else mentioned, using airflow [templates](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) is your best bet.

For example, I use something called `{{ execution_date }}` and pass it as an arg in my airflow code which ensures that whenever I rerun the task, it always runs for a particular input

Note: Latest version has this template deprecated, you could use `{{ ds }}` instead